# Can I remove a Family Sharing child by deleting his account?

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

I started Family Sharing and created a new account for my child, but I was forced to create an icloud.com account, which is not desirable. He already has a Google Account, which may be favourable.

Because he is under 13, I find I cannot actually remove the recently-created account from the family, only transfer him to another family.

It seems possible to self-delete the child's account whilst logged-in as him, which generates a request for parental approval by me.

**However, will this also achieve the aim of removing him from Family Sharing?** I assume, if the child account which had been added to Family Sharing no longer exists, it cannot be a part of Family Sharing.

And then I could start again, creating a new Apple ID using his Gmail address.

Comment: You could just change the AppleID to the GMail address. https://support.apple.com/HT202667

Comment: @Tetsujin Not as I'm looking at it. The primary Apple ID email address is not available for edit. I can only add an additional "contactable at" address, not change the primary one. Maybe due to the weird rules about under-13s.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. If it's using an apple email address. Why not just add the gmail as an alias? I'm not seeing the issue. The ID is just that, an ID. It doesn't really matter what the login details say. My own is an @icloud.com but I route it to my own domain's email address.

Comment: Trying to minimise the number of addresses and accounts flying around.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the gMail address, you can use that as the Apple ID for the child.

[Source](https://www.lifewire.com/remove-child-from-family-sharing-1999091).

## Removing Kids 13 and Under From Family Sharing

Apple doesn't allow you to remove a child under the age of 13 from your Family Sharing (in the U.S., at least; the age is different in other countries). When you add a child that young to your Family Sharing group, they're there to stay until they turn 13.

If you started Family Sharing and added a child under 13, you can't remove them on your own. You have a few ways you can potentially get out of this situation:

### Disband the family

You can [disband the entire Family Sharing group](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201081) and start again. When you create the new group, don't add the child under 13. If you and the child are the only people on your Family Sharing list, you need to transfer them before you can stop Family Sharing.

### Transfer the child to another family

When you add a child under 13 to Family Sharing, you can't delete them, but you can transfer them to another Family Sharing group. To do that, the organizer of another Family Sharing group needs to invite the child to join their group. In this case, the child's Family Sharing account won't be deleted, but it won't be your responsibility any longer.

### Call Apple

If transferring a child to another Family Sharing group isn't an option, call Apple. While the company doesn't give you a way to remove a child from Family Sharing, it has other tools that can help. Call 1-800-MY-APPLE and talk to someone who can provide support for iCloud.

**Note**:
When you call Apple, make sure you have all of the relevant information handy. The customer service representative will need the email address for the account of the child you want to remove. You'll also need a device handy so that you can access your own Apple ID. Apple Support will walk you through the process of removing the child, though the official removal can take up to 7 days.

Comment: The answers are relevant to my situation and factually correct, thanks. However, I'm still not sure whether deleting the child's Apple ID will remove them from the Family, as asked. // FYI, the option to Stop Family Sharing is not available because the child is under 13; he can only be moved to another family, it's ridiculous. // That's why I'm seeking a last resort in deleting the account itself.

Comment: To "delete" an Apple ID you have to contact Apple, that's the only way to do it.  Everything associated with that ID (purchases of apps and music, photos/videos stored in iCloud, etc) will be lost. It should also remove them from FS and they'll never be able to use that account ID again.  This is probably your last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove a child from a family and if you don't want to deal with creating a new family to move the child to, or disband your family, Apple is very unhelpful. However, you may remove it once the child reaches 13 years of age. So, if you want to remove it from your account this is what you can do if you intend on removing the account from your family. You may also delete the account once your done.

Contact apple and tell them you entered the incorrect birthday for your child's account. They will unlock the birthday field, which may only be done once.

Once unlocked, update the birthday so that it will turn 13 the next day. For example, if the current day is 11/27/2020, set the birthday to 11/28/2007. Setting it to a date just under 13 is key, because Apple won't let you pick a date that will make the account older than 13 when you're editing it. At midnight, the account will turn 13, allowing you to remove the account from the family. Once removed, login to the account, and delete it (if you wish).

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a child under 13 from your family sharing group but you can transfer them.

I was unable to transfer using my iPhone.  My wife would never the transfer request. But I was able to do it successfully via my **Mac**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can delete your child's apple id which will require organizer/parent approval.

To delete your child's apple id, follow this step

1. Login to data & privacy using your child apple id
2. Click request to delete your account
3. Send parental consent to delete your child's apple id
4. Check your device/email to approve the apple id deletion
5. Follow the next step

Answer (score 0):

The email address is unrelated to the Apple ID: you don't have to use the actual email address that you use as your apple id. You can create a somebody@icloud.com, then change the contact email address to your gmail address, and simply never use the icloud.com address. I do this: this means my actual email address is not available if someone sees my Apple ID.

You need to log in as your son to change the contact email address in the account settings. Then you can use the gmail address as the contact email, where Apple will send emails and even second factors.